# Date compare between two datetime columns and a constant

Tags: sql, sql-server

Lets say I have this following table:

```
+------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| ID   | CreatedDate             | LastChangedDate         |
+------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| 3965 | 2019-01-23 03:54:44.903 | 2021-03-12 06:24:45.390 |
+------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| 3966 | 2019-01-23 03:55:37.160 | 2021-01-09 04:50:20.697 |
+------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| 3967 | 2019-01-23 03:56:21.197 | 2020-05-11 06:10:14.203 |
+------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| 3968 | 2019-01-23 03:57:07.943 | 2020-05-11 11:28:26.580 |
+------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| 3969 | 2019-01-23 03:58:01.020 | NULL                    |
+------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| 3970 | 2019-01-23 03:58:42.293 | 2021-05-11 09:57:54.553 |
+------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| 4143 | 2019-03-19 04:23:08.003 | 2020-12-14 10:08:38.303 |
+------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| 4144 | 2019-03-19 04:51:14.533 | 2020-12-14 10:05:11.867 |
+------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| 4145 | 2019-03-19 05:16:28.980 | 2019-07-11 07:23:15.803 |
+------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| 4146 | 2019-03-19 05:18:49.550 | 2020-01-02 09:12:13.597 |
+------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| 4808 | 2019-09-17 05:44:54.587 | 2021-01-09 10:35:20.860 |
+------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| 5243 | 2020-01-02 09:07:10.573 | 2021-02-01 16:06:51.770 |
+------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| 5666 | 2020-08-12 07:16:20.617 | 2021-01-09 04:52:25.427 |
+------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| 5877 | 2020-09-05 05:35:56.160 | 2021-01-09 04:51:43.707 |
+------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
```

Now lets say I want to see whether `CreatedDate` or `LastChangedDate` column is greater than '2021-01-09'.
To do the comparison, I need to check if `LastChangedDate` is `NULL` then compare the given date with `CreatedDate` field, else compare with `LastChangedDate` field.

What I have tried so far:

```
DECLARE @test_date as varchar(20) = '2021-01-09'

SELECT ID, CreatedDate, LastChangedDate
FROM #temptable
WHERE CAST(ISNULL(LastChangedDate,CreatedDate) as date) > CAST(@test_date as date)
```

But it is not giving proper output.

What I want is:

```
+------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| ID   | CreatedDate             | LastChangedDate         |
+------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| 3967 | 2019-01-23 03:56:21.197 | 2020-05-11 06:10:14.203 |
+------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| 3968 | 2019-01-23 03:57:07.943 | 2020-05-11 11:28:26.580 |
+------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| 3969 | 2019-01-23 03:58:01.020 | NULL                    |
+------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| 4143 | 2019-03-19 04:23:08.003 | 2020-12-14 10:08:38.303 |
+------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| 4144 | 2019-03-19 04:51:14.533 | 2020-12-14 10:05:11.867 |
+------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| 4145 | 2019-03-19 05:16:28.980 | 2019-07-11 07:23:15.803 |
+------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| 4146 | 2019-03-19 05:18:49.550 | 2020-01-02 09:12:13.597 |
+------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
```

Also here is a [sqlplayground with sample data](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=9f5750dadfb8da8bee86bd9371cfa958)

Comment: What is your desire output?

Comment: @DaminiSuthar
3967,3968,3969,4143,4144,4145,4146

Comment: For future reference its best to make your DBFiddle contain the same data as your question. And yes, always include your desired results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact you shouldn't need any `CAST`s:

- first define your variable as a `date` instead of a string - always use the correct datatype for the data you are storing.
- second use logical operations (`AND`/`OR`) instead of `COALESCE` to make your query sargable i.e. able to use indexes. Anytime you use a function on a column in your `WHERE` clause you run the risk of preventing the use of indexes and slowing your query down.

```
DECLARE @test_date as date = '2021-01-09';

SELECT ID, CreatedDate, LastChangedDate
FROM #temptable
WHERE (LastChangedDate IS NOT NULL AND LastChangedDate > @test_date)
OR (LastChangedDate IS NULL AND CreatedDate > @test_date);
```

Comment: Thanks @Dale K , I will remember your advice

Comment: Plus one for making the query [sargable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable). When indexes are involved, much better for performance.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are comparing only date. So try with compare date and time both.

```
SELECT ID,CreatedDate, LastChangedDate
FROM #temptable WHERE 
 CAST(ISNULL(LastChangedDate,CreatedDate) as datetime) > CAST(@test_date as datetime)
```

Comment: While this works, it would be better if the query were re-written to be [sargable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable) *"....a condition (or predicate) in a query is said to be sargable if the DBMS engine can take advantage of an index to speed up the execution of the query..."*